# Symfony2 : add a new target for assetic finder

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

In my symfony project I have a bundle named Modules that included of many modules that each one saved in a separate directory into **src/ModuleBundle/Modules** directory and they have separate twig files as their templates.

file structure for an sample module named RandomImage

```
src
   ModuleBundle
       Modules
           RandomImage
               Resources
                   views
                   public
```

I don't have any problem with loading twig files for each module but my problem is about assetic:dump function that can't find my modules assetic.

Symfony move into all twig files and fetch all assetic files that listed inside **{% stylesheets %}** and **{% javascripts %}** block or used in **{{ asset() }}** function.

In my research i understand that Symfony search and map assetic in two target

1. assetics listed in base template twig file (e.g. app/Resources/views/base.html.twig)
2. assetics listed in each one of bundles twig files (e.g. src/myBundle/Resources/views/index.html.twig)

How I can add new target for Symfony to fetch assetic files from their twig files?

Comment: I think you should create a Module namespace that contains distinct bundles inside (`src > Modules > RandomImageBundle`), bundle is a synonym of module so your architecture looks really redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Assetic has a configuration for which bundle's to search through - **assetic.bundles** found in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    bundles:

        # Defaults (all currently registered bundles):
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - ...
```

Make sure:

- assetic.bundles is unset or set to ~
- otherwise make sure your bundle is listed in there
- your bundle is registered in **app/AppKernel.php**

In order to change the default ressources of Symfony/AsseticBundle extend ( i.e. via bundle inheritance )

```
vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TemplateResourcesPass.php
```

the default Resources/views folder structure can be found around line 50-70 ( as of Symfony 2.3 )

```
$container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/Resources/'.$bundleName.'/views',
// ...
$bundleDirName.'/Resources/views',
// ...
new DirectoryResourceDefinition('', $engine, array($container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/Resources/views'))
```

The ResourceDefinitions are being loaded in a CompilerPass - read more about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

Comment: **Thank you** for answer but it's not my purpose because ModuleBundle maybe contain some module that saved in a sub directory into ModuleBundle root directory (`src > Acme > ModuleBundle > Modules`) and since the twig files isn't in a Symfony default file structure (`src > Acme > ModuleBundle > Resources > views`) it cant to find their twig files , I want to find where Symfony generate a list of target directories for searching their twig files

Comment: updated my answer with further information. that's what you're looking for right?